# "Animal skin treated" - what does "treated" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, british-english

The skin of animals like cows, buffaloes, goats, crocodiles, snakes and camels are treated and used as leather to make belts, shoes, bags and purses etc.

Can you please explain the meaning of treated in above sentence?

I saw this sentence in my book chapter.

Comment: Animal skins are given a _treatment_ (tanning) to turn them into leather. _Treated_ here means _subjected to a process_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Treated" means processed in this context, here's a relevant [quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchment#Treatments) from wikipedia:

> To make the parchment more aesthetically pleasing or more suitable for
>   the scribes, special *treatments* were used. According to Reed there
>   were a variety of these *treatments*. Rubbing pumice powder into the
>   flesh side of parchment while it was still wet on the frame was used
>   to make it smooth and to modify the surface to enable inks to
>   penetrate more deeply.

Treatment is basically the process of changing some substance properties by mechanical and/or chemical means. Like in, for instance, [water treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_treatment) or surface treatment.